# Wow632 registry redirection in Windows server

Tags: powershell

I am writing a code in PowerShell. It includes registry redirection to WOW6432 node based on machine type. I am using SAPIEN Powershell studio

The IFS-PSlib.ps1 has the following code

```
function Get-WoW6432Env
{
param (
    [string]$Server
)

$ServerType = (Get-WmiObject win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Server).SystemType

if ([IntPtr]::size -eq 8 -and $ServerType -eq "x64-based PC") {# 8 bytes means executing on 64 bit
    $WoW6432Node = "\\WoW6432Node"
}
if ([IntPtr]::size -eq 4 -or $ServerType -eq "X86-based PC") {# 4 bytes means executing on 32 bit
    $WoW6432Node = $null
}

return $WoW6432Node}
```

The Global.ps1 has the code to manipulate registry path HKLM:SOFTWARE\Positive\VersionControl.

I need my code to identify server as 64 bit and then use path HKLM:SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Positive\VersionControl.

But this is not happening, am I missing something here.

PLease suggest

Comment: `[IntPtr]::Size` is on the machine you are running the code from (**your** computer), not the server you are targeting.

Comment: Yes both my computer and the server I am targeting are 64 bit, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using a test based on `[IntPtr]::Size` only gives you the 'bitness' of the **currently running process**, i.e. that is the PowerShell on your machine running in either 64 or 32 bits.
To test if another computer has 64 bit **architecture**, you need to do:

```
# returns '64' or '32'
$bitness = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture -replace '\D'  

# Or do any of these:
# $bitness = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).SystemType -replace '\D' -replace '86', '32'
# $bitness = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).AddressWidth   # slow...
```

If you want that as helper function, you can change it to be

```
function Get-WoW6432Env {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('ComputerName')]
        [string]$Server = $env:COMPUTERNAME  # if not given, default to this computer
    )
    # return either a string '\WoW6432Node' or nothing
    if (((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server).OSArchitecture -replace '\D') -eq '64') {
        '\WoW6432Node'
    }
}
```

Example to use that:

```
$regPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE{0}\Positive\VersionControl' -f (Get-WoW6432Env -Server 'YourServer01')
```

```
If the server to test has 32 bit architecture, $regPath will become 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Positive\VersionControl'  
If the server to test has 64 bit architecture, $regPath will become 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\Positive\VersionControl'
```

<sup>Nowadays, you would rather use `Get-CimInstance` than `Get-WmiObject`. See [here](https://blog.ipswitch.com/get-ciminstance-vs-get-wmiobject-whats-the-difference) why</sup>